# SQL Select syntax

Tags: sql

I've came cross a SQL `SELECT` statement which is different than what I normally see:

```
Select Distinct [Employee: Department_key_historic],[Employee: Department_key_current]
From [shared].[vw_Table]
```

What does the colon do in the above code? I am used to see format like Select table.columnName but never a `:`

Comment: which dbms are we talking about*

Comment: There is no colon in the code.  It is in the middle of a column name.

Comment: Take a look at the actual column names in `[shared].[vw_Table]` and I can almost guarantee that those column names have colons in them.  The colon in the column name is treated no differently than the underscore or the space in the column name; since they're inside square brackets, they're just the column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a SQL Server query.  If that is the case, [] are used to surround object names.  Therefore the : that you see are simply part of the name of the column itself.